# Why does ArgoCD keep saying that it cannot create my application?

Tags: minikube

I am trying to follow the demo at https://www.katacoda.com/vikas-poddar-slalom/scenarios/session-09-lab3-gitops-argocd. I have performed all previous exercises successfully, but still can't get past the **Create App** section.

I have set up the Gitlab repos successfully, pushed the app and config repos, deployed argocd into minikube and portforwarded to the ArgoCD GUI. I am also able to connect with the Git repository but cannot build the app.

Expected Behavior:

Connecct to the config git repo, set up an application then apply CI/CD updates using the app.

Error: When creating the 'New App', I keep getting a red  flag saying:

*Unable to create application: application spec is invalid: InvalidSpecError: Unable to get app details: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = workloads: app path does not exist*

Not sure why it keeps saying that.